# why a variable defined in a node module is shared between two users

Tags: mysql, node.js, memory, pm2

I run a **node** API server with **pm2 cluster mode** that will communicate with a **mysql** DB server.

In module `x.js` I have a code like this:

```js
let insertMappingQuery = ``;
...
...
const constructInsertMappingQuery = () => {
insertMappingQuery += `
    INSERT IGNORE INTO messages_mapping (message_id, contact_id)
    VALUES (` + message_id + `, ` + contact_id + ` + `);`;
}
```

When a user sends a message a function will call module x and the code above is executed for his message (let's say **message_id = 1**)

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO messages_mapping (message_id, contact_id)
    VALUES (1, some_id);
```

then another user sends a message and the code is executed for let's say **message_id = 2** however the query will look like this:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO messages_mapping (message_id, contact_id)
    VALUES (1, some_id);
INSERT IGNORE INTO messages_mapping (message_id, contact_id)
    VALUES (2, some_id);
```

So basically when user two sends a message, this query will contain what user one already executed. **So user one will have his record inserted twice.**

This doesn't happen all the time but it happens a lot (I would say 30% to 50%) and I couldn't find any pattern when this happens.

Users don't have to do it at the same time, there might be some time difference (minutes or even hours).

could this be related to the variable not being cleared in the memory? or a memory leakage of some kind?

I don't understand how two different users will share a variable.

Comment: This question is kind of all over the place, but the immediate observation would be: if you don't want users to share variables, don't declare them outside of the routes that service API calls. Use [autoincrement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) so you don't need to consult and increment things manually, and only ever create queries in the context of requests, not at a global level.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, sorry I forgot to mention that `message_id` is a foreign key, so I don't have a problem with autoincrementing the primary key in the table. 
Could you elaborate on declaring variables? as far as I know, declaring variables inside a module (file), outside of any code block will make them global to that module only.

Comment: "When a user sends a message a function will call module x" = scope all variables to that function, and don't reach out to anything else. That means passing function arguments for things like the session, the db connection, etc. and only declaring request-specific variables (and passing those further on, too) inside that function. Probably related: Node modules are _cached and shared_ rather than required "as separate copies" each time you use `require`, so if you have `const a = require('whatever')` somewhere, and `const b = require('whatever')` somewhere else, they point to _the same thing_

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Thank you for the hint and the quick reply. I didn't know that `require` caches modules. I will update the question with an answer.

Comment: You answer is really, really bad. Don't do that. Instead write your code so that it can be invoked in contained calls. Like we do for every bit of normal JS, and like any good tutorial on writing code for Node teaches you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `require` caches modules and all subsequent `require` calls are given *the same* things, so write something that exports a function, or class, so that you can safely call/instantiate things without variables getting shared.

For example:

```js
const db = require(`your/db/connector`);

const Mapper = {
  addToMessageMapping: async function(messageId, contactId) {
    const query = `
      INSERT IGNORE INTO messages_mapping (message_id, contact_id)
      VALUES (${message_id}, ${contact_id});
    `;
    ...
    return db.run(query);
  },
  ...
}

module.exports = Mapper;
```

And of course this could have been a class, too, or it could even have been that function directly - the only thing that changes is how you make it run that non-conflicting-with-any-other-call function.

Now, consumers of this code simply trust that the following is without side effects:

```js
const mapper = require('mapper.js');
const express, app, etc, whatever = ...

....

app.post(`/api/v1/mappings/message/:msgid`, (req, res, next) => {
  const post = getPOSTparamsTheUsualWay();

  mapper.addToMessageMapping(req.params.msgId, post.contactId)
        .then(() => next());
        .catch(error => next(error));

}, ..., moreMiddleware, ... , (req,res) => {
  res.render(`blah.html`, {...});
});
```

Also note that template strings exist *specifically* to prevent string composition by concatenating strings with `+`, the whole point is that they can take `${...}` inside them and template in "whatever is in those curly braces" (variables, function calls, any JS really).

(The second power they have is that you can prefix tag them with a function name and that function will run as part of the templating action, but not a lot of folks need this on a daily basis. `${...}` templating though? Every day, thousands of times).

And of course on a last note: it looks like you're creating raw SQL, which is always a bad idea. Use prepared statements for whatever database library you're using: it supports them, and means any user-input is made safe. Right now, someone could post to your API with a message id that's `); DROP TABLE messages_mapping; --` and done: your table's gone. Fun times.

Comment: Thank you for the notes below. Two questions:
1. by prepared statements you mean an ORM?
2. If I'm using templating then it means I'm still writing raw SQL, right?

Comment: 1: I mean a prepared statement. It's something that every database connector offers (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries, https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Prepared%20statements, https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback, etc.) 2: correct. Never fire off raw SQL with values that you just copied over from somewhere. You have no way of guaranteeing those values are even remotely safe.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I didn't know that `require`ing a module will cache it and reuse it. Thus global variables in that module will be cached too.

So the best solution here is to avoid using global variables and restructure the code. However if you need a quick solution you can use:

```js
delete require.cache[require.resolve('replaceWithModulePathHere')]
```

**Example:**

```js
let somefuncThatNeedsModuleX = () => {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./x')];
  const x = require('./x');
}
```

Comment: What? No, don't do this, this is ridiculous. Instead, you export a function (directly, in a plain object, as part of a class, whatever you need) that you can `require` in and call in a way such that each call is a new context,without any shared, mutable variables. If you need to interfere with Node's require cache, you are guaranteed doing things wrong.

Comment: Yes I eventually did this, however deleting the cache before requiring also works. I understand it is not ideal, but it can save you sometimes.

Comment: Then you don't understand it quite well enough: if your code has to reset the underlying Node module cache, then _you are absolutely and without question writing really bad code_ and the solution is definitely not this, it's fixing your code. Even if "this works", it's such a bad hack that you should never, ever, do this, or advocate this.